# Apache + passenger or passenger_standalone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache2, passenger

I have an environment where my app is running on multiple machines on mongrel and is getting load balanced by Apache. I am switching mongrel to passenger. Would passenger standalone be a better idea or Apache+passenger on every machine?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092873/rails-is-passenger-standalone-suitable-for-production-deployment

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would say Apache+Passenger is a good choice when you have many different apps on your server and you have to make use of Apache's VirtualHost directive a lot. In case you have only a single app and are trying to balance the load, apache brings a lot of overhead, especially if you have it on every host just for load balancing purposes. You should then consider using nginx with thin which both have a very small memory footprint.

Comment: Why would you advice using nginx with thin instead of using nginx with Passenger?

Comment: I don't and removed the last sentence from my answer.